# Estimate from a differential inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let $[0,T]$ be some finite interval. Consider the differential inequality
$$f'(t)\leq C t^{\alpha}f(t)^2+g(t),$$
where $g$ is positive and bounded and $\alpha >0$, $C<0$. Can we get a bound for $f(t)$, $0<t\leq T$ in terms of $f(0)$ and $g$?
Edit: Let me just clarify what I am aiming or. If there is no $g$ in the inequality we can divide by $f(t)^2$ and integrate on both sides such that
$$\frac{1}{f(t)}\geq \frac{D}{\alpha + 1}t^{\alpha+1}+\frac{1}{f(0)},$$
$D=-C$.
Hence
$$f(t)\leq \frac{D f(0)\frac{1}{t^{\alpha +1 }}+\alpha + 1}{(\alpha + 1)f(0)}.$$
Can we reach something similar when $g$ is present?
Separating the "variables" is not so easy as we don't know a potential for $\frac{g}{f}$. I also tried variation of the parameters but I failed. Is there maybe some other way do this?

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you asking if $f$ is bounded on $[0,T]$ ?  If so,  then since $f$ is continuous (because its derivative exists) and the interval $[0,T]$ is compact then there is a bound for $f$ on that interval.

Comment: @Dan I edited my question

Comment: If $C$ is positive, $f$ is nondecreasing. That means the maximum value is going to be $f_*(T)$, where $f_*$ satisfies $f_*' = Ct^\alpha f(t)^2 + g(t)$. If $C$ is negative, things get trickier.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Is it possible to see this by a concrete computation?

Comment: I edited my post so that my question hopefully becomes a little bit more clear.

Comment: Let $\beta = D/(1+\alpha)$. Then letting $f(t) = \beta h'(t^{1+a})/h(t^{1+a})$ gives the linear differential inequality $h''(s) \le (\beta^2/D) s^{-\alpha/(1+\alpha)}g(s^{1/(1+\alpha)})h(s)$, with initial conditions $h(0) = \beta$ and $h'(0) = f(0)$. Not entirely sure it helps, but linearity is always nice.

Comment: @eyeballfrog It's not true to say that $f^{'} \geq 0$ if $C>0$? Consider this example: $g=0$, $C=1$ and $f(t)= e^{-t}$, then it obviously satisfies the inequality (because the left side is negative and the right rside is positive!)  but $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @Dan Argh, of course you are right. Though I believe the conclusion $f(t) \le f_*(T)$ is still correct.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks for your suggestion. I have to think about it if it gives something i desire...